# validation rule in yii

Tags: php, validation, yii

The following is the validation rule

```
public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            // username and password are required
            array('oldPassword', 'required'),
            array('oldPassword', 'authenticate'),
                    ....
        );
    }
public function authenticate($attribute,$params)
{
    $this->userModel=User::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id);
    if($this->userModel!=null){
      if(!$this->userModel->validatePassword($this->oldPassword))
        $this->addError($attribute, "Incorrect current password");
    }
}
```

Everything works fine but the problem lies here... when I keep the oldPassword blank both the validation error for "required" & "authentication' are shown whereas I want to show the error msg for the first one,if not blank then the later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a condition in `authenticate()` to only validate if `oldPassword` is not empty:

```
 public function authenticate($attribute, $params) {
      if ($this->oldPassword) {
          ...
      }
 }
```